# django rest framework - browsable api remove delete

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view:

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        instance = self.get_object()
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, instance)
        serializer = PasswordFolderSerializer(instance, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except Http404:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

When not logged in I will get a 403 which is good however the "DELETE" button still shows in the browsable API.  how do I get rid of this?  Here is my permission:

```
class CanRetrievePasswordFolder(permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        access_levels = ['Owner', 'Admin', 'Read']
        if get_permission_level(request, obj) is None:
            return False
        else:
            level = AccessLevel.objects.get(pk=get_permission_level(request, obj).level_id).name
            if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
                return True
            else:
                for access in access_levels:
                    if level == access:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really stupid, I had to add IsAuthenticated to my permissions tuple on the view like so:

```
permission_classes_by_action = {'create': [CanCreatePasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated],
                                'list': [CanListPasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated],
                                'retrieve': [CanRetrievePasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated],
                                'partial_update': [CanUpdatePasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated],
                                'update': [CanUpdatePasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated],
                                'destroy': [CanDestroyPasswordFolder, IsAuthenticated]}
```